# password given for encrypting data

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, password-encryption, elgamal

I have done a project in python. Its an Elliptic Curve Cryptography encryption decryption system I used EC ElGamal Algorithm for encryption and decryption. The points on the curve is plotted as shown in the following code:

```
def prepare_curve_parameters(self):
    len_password = len(self.password)
    self.prime_nums = get_nPrimeNumbers(127 + len_password)

    P = self.prime_nums[-1]
    D = self.prime_nums[len_password]

    password_block = [ord(x) for x in self.password]
    if len_password % 2 != 0:
        password_block.append(len_password)

    print ('password ascii', password_block)

    half_len = len(password_block) / 2
    block1 = password_block[:half_len]
    block2 = password_block[half_len:]
    print('password block 1', block1)
    print('password block 2', block2)

    byte_array1 = array.array('B', block1)
    M = zlib.crc32(byte_array1) & 0xffffffff

    byte_array2 = array.array('B', block2)
    N = zlib.crc32(byte_array2) & 0xffffffff

    print("M={}, N={}".format(M, N))

    A = M % P
    B = N % P

    print("Curve [A={}, B={}, P={}]".format(A, B, P))

    self.a = A
    self.b = B
    self.p = P
    self.d = D

 def get_cryptosystem(self):

    self.prepare_curve_parameters()
    ec = EC(self.a, self.b, self.p)

    rand_perf_square = get_randomPerfSquare(self.p)
    g, _ = ec.at(rand_perf_square)

    print('g', g)

    self.eg = ElGamal(ec, g)
```

The problem is whenever i gave a password most of the time that password is not working and it shows following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CryptoSystem.py", line 144, in <module>
    main()
  File "CryptoSystem.py", line 140, in main
   decrypt(im_file, password, dec_file)
  File "CryptoSystem.py", line 114, in decrypt
    img_str, status = crypto.decrypt(enc_file)
  File "CryptoSystem.py", line 82, in decrypt
   cipher = pickle.load(open(im_file, 'rb'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
   return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
   dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 897, in load_persid
   self.append(self.persistent_load(pid))
 AttributeError: Unpickler instance has no attribute 'persistent_load'
```

Comment: You have to add the full error traceback to the question

Comment: I have added it now

Comment: From the error traceback, it seems your error is in the `decrypt` function from `CryptoSystem.py`, but you didn't include that function's code. In fact no lines from the traceback are in the code you included!

Comment: but this error is when i perform encryption

Comment: ok, but the error shows code that you didn't include. If we can't see the code that is causing the error, how do we expect us to understand the error and find its cause?

Comment: The error traceback doesn't lie - the `decrypt` function is being called in line 140, and the error is inside it